# Selenium remove arguments

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know there is a way to add arguments to the options

```
options.add_argument(option)
```

but is there a way to remove them by code? I want to automate across several settings but sometimes I just want to clear the previous setting and use the default rather than defining a new setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to remove arguments from options. This is because it designed in a way if you need the defaults, just create the new option instance.